# Python implementation of quicksort

Tags: python, sorting, quick-sort

My teacher often tells me that I don't take full advantage of Python capabilities, I would like to know if my implementation of Quicksort is good enough and how could I improve it, aside from doing it in-place

```
def quickSort(l):
    if len(l) > 1:
        l,iPiv = partition(l)
        return quickSort(l[:iPiv]) + [l[iPiv]] + quickSort(l[iPiv+1:])
    else:
        return l

def partition(l):
    i = 1
    iPiv = 0
    for j in range(1,len(l)):
        if l[j] <= l[iPiv]:
            l[i],l[j] = l[j],l[i]
            i += 1
    l[i-1],l[iPiv] = l[iPiv],l[i-1]
    return l,i-1
```

Comment: You defined `particionar()`, but you call `partition()`. Please make up your mind?

Comment: Sorry, I translated it when posting, particionar was the spanish name of the function :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks quite nice, but I suggest renaming some variables and methods:

- Rename `l` to `items`, because `l` is just too short and hard to read
- Rename `iPiv` to `pivot`, because it's more readable
- Rename `quickSort` to `quicksort` because it's very widely known and used that way

To follow [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), put a space after comma in tuples, for example `l, iPiv` instead of `l,iPiv`

When you have this kind of code:

> ```
> if cond:
>     # do something
>     return x
> else:
>     # do something
>     return y
> ```

... you can drop the `else` and just use `return y`

The result:

```
def quicksort(items):
    if not len(items) > 1:
        return items
    items, pivot = partition(items)
    return quicksort(items[:pivot]) + [items[pivot]] + quicksort(items[pivot+1:])


def partition(items):
    i = 1
    pivot = 0
    for j in range(1, len(items)):
        if items[j] <= items[pivot]:
            items[i], items[j] = items[j], items[i]
            i += 1
    items[i-1], items[pivot] = items[pivot], items[i-1]
    return items, i-1
```

Comment: I'm really thankful about your suggestions. Naming: that's my daily struggle! I chose your answer because it improved my existing code, and, while I love list comprehensions, they aren't available in all languages, as for parallel assignment, concatenation and splicing, python just gives you shortcuts, but the main logic can be applied elsewhere. Again, thank you

Answer (score 8):

> My teacher often tells me that I don't take full advantage of Python capabilities

Try partitioning with list comprehensions.

```
import random


def quicksort(s):
    len_s = len(s)
    if len_s < 2:
        return s

    pivot = s[random.randrange(0, len_s)]

    L = [x for x in s if x < pivot]
    E = [x for x in s if x == pivot]
    G = [x for x in s if x > pivot]

    return quicksort(L) + E + quicksort(G)
```

This is Pythonic, compact and faster than your `partition` function.

Furthermore, notice the pivot is random. Your original code always uses zero for the pivot. [This results in worst-case O(n^2) complexity for sorted inputs.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot) A random pivot mitigates this risk.

As for style, [the answer from @janos](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/69236/27318) offers solid guidance also.

Comment: Wow! that's a neat way to use list comprehensions! as for the random pivot, I'm aware of the issues about choosing always the first element as pivot, I just made it that way for simplicity, that's why I used the iPiv variable despite it being 0 everytime